# centos 7.5 supermicro x11sta-t - when I set kernel parameter memmap= the kernel hangs on boot

Tags: parameters, kernel

I am using some middleware that expects memory to be reserved with the memmap= kernel parameter.

With centos 7.5 supermicro x11sta-t - when I set kernel parameter memmap= the kernel hangs on boot.

Is there some new limitation on this time-honored means of reserving a large contiguous array of memory for drivers to avoid scatter-gather?

Answer (score 0):

My time-honored memory failed me yet again. I couldn't find my notes on the process and tried to work from memory.

When configuring memmap= from /etc/default/grub, you MUST escape the '\' and '$' characters on the command line. So if you want:

memmap=64M$4G

then you MUST use

memmap=64M\$4G

in the /etc/default/grub file. This ends up being

memmap=64M$4G

in the grub menu, which will actually work.

Don't fall in this hole that *I* seem to keep falling into...

Answer (score 0):

A note to @Nufosmatic's answer.

I am working on Fedora 36 and by default GRUB2 uses BootLoaderSpec (BLS). BLS uses `blscfg` command to read a `.conf` file in `/boot/loader/entries/`. It seems that `$` is always eaten by `blscfg` regardless how many `\` you add before it.

So for @Nufosmatic's solution to work, also disable BLS by setting `GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false` in `/etc/default/grub`, then generate a new `grub.cfg` by `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Related RedHat/Fedora bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2102303
I was able to get this working with BLS enabled. See the comments in the previously mentioned bug.